# How does the Dispatcher thread work in wpf a UI control

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

How does the Dispatcher thread work in wpf a UI control?

Comment: please comment for voted down..

Comment: Please be a little bit more precise in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit.

If you have a long running task, delegate it to a background thread using a BackGroundWorker, and then you won't need to use the dispatcher to pass messages back to the UI. [This is a very good article.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx)

---

Its a very broad question. I suggest you start here with [WPF Architecture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750441.aspx).

> Most objects in WPF derive from
>   DispatcherObject, which provides the
>   basic constructs for dealing with
>   concurrency and threading. WPF is
>   based on a messaging system
>   implemented by the dispatcher. This
>   works much like the familiar Win32
>   message pump; in fact, the WPF
>   dispatcher uses User32 messages for
>   performing cross thread calls.
>
> There are really two core concepts to
>   understand when discussing concurrency
>   in WPF – the dispatcher and thread
>   affinity.
>
> During the design phase of WPF, the
>   goal was to move to a single thread of
>   execution, but a non-thread
>   "affinitized" model. Thread affinity
>   happens when a component uses the
>   identity of the executing thread to
>   store some type of state. The most
>   common form of this is to use the
>   thread local store (TLS) to store
>   state. Thread affinity requires that
>   each logical thread of execution be
>   owned by only one physical thread in
>   the operating system, which can become
>   memory intensive. In the end, WPF’s
>   threading model was kept in sync with
>   the existing User32 threading model of
>   single threaded execution with thread
>   affinity. The primary reason for this
>   was interoperability – systems like
>   OLE 2.0, the clipboard, and Internet
>   Explorer all require single thread
>   affinity (STA) execution.
>
> Given that you have objects with STA
>   threading, you need a way to
>   communicate between threads, and
>   validate that you are on the correct
>   thread. Herein lies the role of the
>   dispatcher. The dispatcher is a basic
>   message dispatching system, with
>   multiple prioritized queues. Examples
>   of messages include raw input
>   notifications (mouse moved), framework
>   functions (layout), or user commands
>   (execute this method). By deriving
>   from DispatcherObject, you create a
>   CLR object that has STA behavior, and
>   will be given a pointer to a
>   dispatcher at creation time.

Comment: hmm.. my doubt is when a long running process is happening behind the UI, that time WPF UI will not Respond or using dispatcher thread it can be solved?